# Regex decimal number with 3rd decimal either 0 or 5

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that accepts a decimal with up to 3 decimal places

**If there is a 3rd decimal place it must either be 0 or 5**

**Passing tests:**

```
1
1.0
1.12
0.12
.12
.125
0.125
0.120
123.000
```

**Failing Test:**

```
0.0121
abc1 //anything obiously that is not a decimal number
```

This is what I have so far `^\d*((\d\.)|(\.\d))?\d{0,1}$` which gives me a decimal with 2 places so just need to add `[05]` I believe

How can this be done?

Comment: If "the last decimal place" can only be 0 or 5, then how is `1.12` valid? Or is it "the third decimal point, if it exists, can only be 0 or 5"?

Comment: If there is a 3rd decimal is must be either 0 or 5 @JoachimSauer

Comment: Yes just think of it as a currencey value where if a 3rd decimal place exisits it must be a 0 or a 5 @falsetru

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this passes tests, is this what you looking for?

```
^\d+$|^\d*[.]\d{0,2}[05]?$
```

if no "only dot" allowed, then it becomes:

```
^\d+(?:[.]\d{0,2}[05]?)?$|^[.]\d{1,2}[05]?$
```

Comment: Good solution, personally I'd prefer `\.` over `[.]`, but that's just a matter of taste.

Comment: It seems to match a simple dot `.`.

Comment: Hmm how can this be modified to fail on a single dot? @sp00m

Comment: quick fix, but obviously can be improved `^\d+$|^\d+[.]\d{0,2}[05]?$|^[.]\d{1,2}[05]?$`

Comment: @ojhawkins, please check new one